# Dual boot with ubuntu and windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am facing a problem of dual boot in my laptop. I have SSD drive of 256 GB and HDD drive of 1 tb. Windows 10 installed on my SSD drive.

When I try to dual boot it doesn't show my SSD and also HDD. And in SATA config I have only AHCI mode and intel rst premium with intel optane system acceleration.

How can I dual boot my laptop?
I tried many youtube tutorials but none of them worked.

Comment: Hi Shantanu. Can you find out, wheter you use EFI or BIOS boot? (for each Windows and Linux)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 won't boot after dual boot installation - Optane volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume)

Comment: How can I dual boot? If you want to boot into Ubuntu, just remove the USB or SSD drive. And if you want to boot into Windows, Plug in USB and change the Boot order on your Firmware with USB coming 1st. You can also add Windows OS on your etc/grub.d/40_custom. Then you can opt to boot into Windows or Ubuntu. To check which partition is your Windows installed, use “ls” on the grub boot command line.

Comment: can anyone help me please??