# Did Ubuntu and Grub just delete my Windows data and life's work?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, bios

I'm pretty much having the same issue as this guy with the same exact system (HP+Intel MB+ Optane).

I've had no issue live usb booting in the past but it seems like getting the job done is getting more difficult.

My setup is am HP spectre with Intel bios + Optane

Pretty much I followed standard install procedure and everything looked to follow smoothly. I guess my first mistake was using the recommended partitions. I don't know what happened but it looked like the install worked. I had trouble booting so I ran boot-repair and everything seemed okay. However I was able to boot into Ubuntu but not windows. I can't leave the windows repair prompts.

Now whats scaring me is that my windows files on Ubuntu are gone. I don't know what happened. It's showing relics of the OS but I don't see any of my personal files. In my windows partition all the data was is a NTFS formatted partition. I was surprised when I saw all my data was gone and replaced `/mounted` with `/media/myusername/windows`.

Now I bring up Optane because before this whole ordeal, I had 1 TB worth of storage. The doors showed the two physical disks under the optane volumes. Right now however it's showing that the small 30GB storage is an incomplete Optane and the rest (970GB) is a "Non-Raid physical disk".

I'm not sure what's going on and I'm fearing the worst :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Did Ubuntu delete my life's work?". I have to ask, did you really not take a backup when re-partitioning your drives and installing a new operating system? What guy are you talking about? In any case, were you trying to install Ubuntu? Which version? What installation instructions did you follow?

Comment: Surely there multiple backups of one's life work, so nothing to worry about. There are some NTFS partitions in the screenshot, but no way for us to tell what's there.

Comment: Well I have backups but most recent is 6 months! I've installed Ubuntu more than one in the past but in the other hand this was a new computer. I was installing version 20. I followed this guide https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/ but didn't do manual partitions, just the recommended, no delete option.

Comment: @MikeA, this might sound silly, but have you tried navigating to `/media/myusername/windows` to see whether your files are still there?

Comment: @kuranakat Yes there is nothing there. I can only load windows recovery from the efi file. In the command prompt I see the C drive with program files, Users, Windows, etc but no personal data. It's as if Ubuntu did a not do a format but a refresh of the system, or unless there is some windows/bios feature that wiped the drive itself.If it's the latter Im suspecting it's the whole Optane thing.Somehow it got broken where the small drive is Optane and that large drive isnt. They are both supposed to be Optane.They both hve to be either/or. There is no option for me to make the large drive optane

Comment: Without seeing what you ticked and didn't tick in the partitioning part of the installer, it'll be difficult to know exactly what happened, but is it possible you didn't untick the "Format this partition" checkbox? The fact that there is nothing in the partition makes me think it's been formatted. The guide you link to was written for Ubuntu 14.04 six years ago and the installer has changed a bit since. Just to be sure, can you please run `sudo df -h` and paste the output to your question?

Comment: Been running data recovery software on it for a while now. Looks like a total lose. I had trouble with installing Ubuntu and went through multiple installs using both the recommended settings and the self partition. So maybe I did screw up somewhere. What I can say is that Ubuntu and Optane DO NOT mix. My main drive is no longer showing to Optane enabled. Yes there other is which doesn't even make sense.

Comment: See: HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15 -cx0049nr Disable Optane memory
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved
 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume Intel Optane - See Intel response that no performance difference between RAID & AHCI.
https://communities.intel.com/thread/121155