# Not able to dual boot my hp laptop with windows 10 already installed

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, hp, 20.04

I have HP Envy-x360 15m-dr1012dx. I created an empty 100 gb partition for ubuntu. I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04. Whenever Ubuntu installation is complete the Grub menu won't appear laptop goes directly into windows boot loader.
So i tried to manually boot from efi file "grubx64.efi" which is located in ubuntu folder(efi system partition). It gives me an error "The selected boot device failed. Press enter to continue."
I don't know what I'm doing wrong or is it hp that has messed up the bios.

Comment: Taking in account of the device you're using is a laptop with a single hard drive installed, Non-booting Linux has multiple reasons to fail booting, Let's just narrow down out options here, Say, Have you partitioned the the Linux installation with appropriate sda swaps and root drives it needs? Did it booted into the Linux system the first time after the installation?

Comment: I did create partition for swap, root and home of 6gb, 20gb and 74gb respectively. And no it does not boot into linux it boots directly into windows. The ubuntu installation is successful every time.

Comment: Did you install properly. Did you install both in the same boot mode? Is Ubuntu 1st in boot sequence in firmware settings. Also why didn't you use install alongside windows option. How did you do the partitioning with the something else option. Give us Info.

Comment: Alright, As far as I know, While installing ubuntu, it must have asked you to choose whether to sideload and dual-boot it with windows or not. What did you choose?

Comment: Make sure that ubuntu is first in boot sequence. It sounds like that is the problem. I personally keep ubuntu 2nd as I use windows most. You should still be able to access ubuntu by going to boot options (probably F12).Please reply to comments so we can help.

Comment: Thanks but its is fine and working now...

Comment: I chose something else it is working now. I did a very silly mistake

Comment: Thanks for you help 

Comment: Good to know that. Please edit the question to include what you did that fixed it and close the question so that others can find answers easily.

Answer (score 1):

Do not know HP 360 models. But lots of posts.

HP Spectre x360 Disable Optane (should use gpt to boot installer in UEFI mode, but MBR may work)

[Windows 10 won't boot after dual boot installation - Optane volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume)

HP X360 Update UEFI F20

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220

HP Pavillion X360 13-a220nw

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359510 &

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1858477#p1858477

HP Envy x360 with Core i5-10210U Intel UHD Graphics Hardware Acceleration 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2432438

[Guide] Install Ubuntu 18.04 on HP Spectre x360 13"

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2422113