# Dualboot Ubuntu freeze of boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, freeze

I used Ubuntu for a while (dualboot with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04) but now when I try to boot Ubuntu, it freezes at this screen

[image: frozen screen]

I have the same screen with a loading symbol but I get stuck when the loading symbol disappears
Thank you in advance for your help  (grub works)

Edit :
-  I tried to replace “quiet splash” by “no splash” and I have a black screen 
- I also tried to add “nomodeset”
- And I tried to use boot-repair from a live usb, it repaired but I still can’t boot my Ubuntu
- I tried the recovery mode 
- And I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M

Sorry if I haven’t answered at some of questions I’m not good in English, thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean by (grub works)? Can you boot from a Live Ubuntu USB?

Comment: I can start grub, and I tried to start a Ubuntu live usb but I can’t choose the usb in the boot option menu

Comment: I said nothing I’m trying to do an usb live

Comment: I tried a boot-repair It doesn’t work

Comment: Please edit the question and add all the new information in the question.

Comment: Boot-Repair primarily is to fix boot to grub menu issues or issues with grub. You are past that if you get grub menu & that screen. Try second menu item in grub menu, or recovery mode. Do you get to Ubuntu terminal? If so some sort of graphic issue. What video do you have?

Comment: I have put all the new information in the question ☺️, thank you for your help

Comment: Do you know if your computer makes use of the Intel's Optane technology? if so you may find the solution in this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume

Comment: Actually I don’t have optane technology but Rapid technology