# Common failed to install grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Thanks in advance for any help provided. I have been at this for a few days now and have no idea what to do. After many attempts at installing ubuntu as a dual boot w/ windows, nothing has worked.

I've done boot repair many times and have attempted manual grub install via the common mounting steps that are seen all around the internet.

For my last attempt at using boot repair, I got an error and received the following link describing the error.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b9DRRh8Mvn/

EDIT: I installed Linux without grub using ubiquity -b in the terminal.

I am using an HP spectre x360 15.6" w/ the following specs:

Processor: Intel i7

GPU: Intel IrisXe Graphics.

SSD: NVMe Intel 512 GB.

If anyone needs any other information from me to help please let me know and thank you.

Comment: Hi @Jeff it says the log that are two nvme units. Does it have an optane memory or something like that? Is your system still booting directly to windows?

Comment: Yes it has intel optane and i can still boot into windows

Comment: Thats your issue...I Had to remove optane (where just 16gb) and disable rst on my daughter notebook to dual boot. Notebok came with 16gb Optane plus 1tb normal HDD. I replaced both of then with 1TB nvme and disabled rst. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Look here..

[How to use Intel Optane Memory for SSD Caching](https://www.codenotary.com/blog/ubuntu-how-to-use-intel-optane-memory-for-ssd-caching/)

and here..
[Is Intel® Optane™ Memory Supported on Linux*?](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000056875/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html)

My experience was that the 16GB did not improve system performance. So I just left the machine with 1TB nvme and it is working great.

Regards and good luck.
JP.

PS: Important.. to disable rst you need to disable in windows (by software) first and later in bios.

Comment: Success!
Thanks alot @jpbrain. I really appreciate your help.

Here are the steps I took below for anyone else having these problems.


1. Disable Intel RST in software in Windows
2. Disable and format the Optane drive in BIOS
3. Run the liveUSB and install Ubuntu Fresh on the new free 28GB Optane drive.
4. Run boot repair because unfortunately the installer still attempted to install grub to my main nvme0n1 drive.
5. Reboot

The 28GB limit on the Optane drive might not be a viable solution for some but its perfect for me.

Comment: Hello @Jeff.. I am quite new in helping through ask Ubuntu. I think you can edit my answer with the comment you just posted so it gets clear how did you solved it. Thanks.

Comment: Similar just for reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume