# Ubuntu Budgie installer not detecting partitions of a SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, ubuntu-budgie

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu Budgie with Windows 11 without losing any data or formatting, I am on a HP Spectre x360 14 with Intel SSD 1Tb and Intel Optane, the NVME SSD is in GPT and I use UEFI. I have cut about 100Gb off my C: drive for it. When I run the installation from a USB drive written by Rufus, the installer does not detect my windows installation and when I click on something else, it detects both the SSD and the Optane but does not see any partitions. Could someone help me please? I am starting to get mad, because I have tried many fixes but none work.

Comment: Boot the USB as UEFI and have unpartitioned free space. Don't create partitions ahead of time- the Ubuntu installer won't consider them suitable. If you meet both of these qualifications you should get a guided "install along windows" option (though win 11 might not)  The first sentence of your question implies that you don't have good backups- not wise especially if you are not experienced with installing operating systems or manipulating partitions and file systems. Even experienced users make mistakes. Always plan for the worst case scenario.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Turned off RAID and changed to AHCI? But you have to install AHCI drivers into Windows first. HP Spectre x360 Disable Optane (should use gpt to boot installer in UEFI mode
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345338/common-failed-to-install-grub
HP X360 Update UEFI F20, probably newer now
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION: Disable Intel Optane in the Windows Optane program.
CONCLUSION: Enabled Optane causes trouble with Ubuntu.
The big thanks goes to oldfred for helping me solve this issue.

Comment: David and @oldfred the answer might be improved by adding the reason and/or link to relevant previous question / issue so that future visitors with similar problems can understand and adapt the solution to their case.