# Can I install Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 11 Secure (TPM) on a fairly new HP Laptop - Spectre x360 2-in-1 13.5"?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, secure-boot

It's not on the Ubuntu Secure-boot 20.04 certified hardware list, but a close more  expensive HP Laptop or two are: https://ubuntu.com/certified?q=&category=Laptop&vendor=HP&release=20.04+LTS

Does anybody have any luck? I searched questions, dual-boot . . . nothing so far.

**Background**:
I've had previous versions of Ubuntu dual boot with Windows 10.

I tried this with a recently purchased Asus Laptop running/installed Windows 10-S out of the box; registered the Laptop to get the manuals, squished down Windows 10 partition, and installed Ubuntu on its partitions.

It ran for a while, then intermittently crashed,(new firmware), then kept losing the wireless connection. So I turned off secure boot in the BIOS, used EFI boot, reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked intermittently.

Oddly, Windows 10 worked fine. Except, later I saw a "No adapter fault"  running the self-test in the bloatware with Windows 10. So I did a factory recovery and brought it back.

Now I want to try with a little newer Laptop (2021):

- HP Spectre x360 2-in-1 13.5"
- Model:14-ea1023dx

Comment: If it is not on the list all you can do is try.

Comment: You probably need 21.10 or maybe 22.04 when released in April. You definitely need newest kernels & drivers. Or may need to use ppa to add newer kernels than included by default. HP Spectre x360 Disable Optane (should use gpt to boot installer in UEFI mode
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345338/common-failed-to-install-grub
HP X360 Update UEFI F20, probably newer now
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220