# Ubuntu on HP ENVY x360 15-eu0175ng not working

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, hp

I just bought a brand new Convertibel Laptop  HP ENVY x360 15-eu0175ng with a Ryzen 7 5700u. I wanted to install Ubuntu 20.04.5 on it. I always manage to get in the GNU GRUB menu and select ,,Try or install Ubuntu". But after this it gets stuck at the HP/Ubuntu Logo loading forever until you Power it off. I have not to much expirience in other OS than Windows but a general understanding of computers and software

I have tried different versions of Ubuntu 20.04.5 and 22.04.1 and both have the same issue. I also tried nomodeset instead of quiet splash. With nomodeset the Installation gets stuck at various loading points or just Black screens completly. I also tried with different usb sticks and secure boot on/off. I found nothing so far to even got to the ubuntu screen

Comment: If new system, you need the very latest version. Do not even try 20.04, You may even need newer kernels & drivers than in 22.04. Have you updated UEFI firmware & if SSD, the SSD firmware? Do you have Optane? Have you reviewed UEFI settings? HP Spectre x360 Disable Optane (should use gpt to boot installer in UEFI mode
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345338/common-failed-to-install-grub
HP X360 Update UEFI F20, probably newer now
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220

Comment: Is Windows installed on the laptop? If so, make sure that Windows fast boot is turned off and Windows is completely shutdown prior to installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Windows 11 is installed on this Laptop. I just uptadet the Firmware and I do not have Optane. I also disabled Fastboot. But nothing seems to have helped. When I tried it agine I noticed that just before the loading screen there is a Massage for about 0.5 second wich status AE_not_found. But it after half a second it goes away and I am stuck in the loading screen until I Power off agine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)