# Ubuntu in hp spectre x360 14 (2024)

Tags: 22.04

I am using an Hp spectre x360 14" 2024, but it is impossible for me to install Ubuntu 22.04.4. Is there anyone within the community who has managed to do it?

Comment: Is that an UEFI only system. Mfg are making UEFI only systems now. It seems HP has used x360 for years, so many models. Not sure then what issues carry from older systems to newer. You may need 24.04 which is in development, so not yet supported here. And then you are testing it. Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmare? Are you dual booting with Windows? May not directly apply: Optane now obsolete, but maybe other issue
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345338/common-failed-to-install-grub

Comment: "impossible" is too vague to offer useful advice. Please edit your question to clearly describe the failure. Explain the actions you took before failure. Use actual wording you see on the screen.

Comment: Hello,

first of all, thank you very much for your comments. I just bought the new HP Spectre x360 with Intel i7 15.5, 14" (2024). I have been using this Spectre family model for many years, probably more than 10. Whenever I used Ubuntu, I never had problems with the installation. Sometimes, some hardware didn't work entirely, but generally, the operating system remained stable to get the work done. Unfortunately, with this new model, the computer hangs for a long time with the following message:

Comment: [2.318754] hid-generic 001F:8087:0AC2.0008: didraw7: SENSOR HUB HID v2.00 Device [hid-ishtp 8087:0AC2] on.

After 10 minutes, the following message appears:

Unable to find a medium containing a live file system Attempt interactive netboot from a URL?

I am using Ubuntu version 22.04.4 (03.06.2024).

Due to my love for Ubuntu, I am willing to collaborate in any way I can. If needed, we can arrange a virtual meeting. As I mentioned, I have over 10 years of experience with Ubuntu and HP Spectre. I am at your disposal.

Comment: A few moments ago I also tried with Ubuntu 24.04 (03.06.2024). The error that appears during the installation is the following: usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Generic

Comment: I have installed ubuntu 20.04. With this version I can install the operating system, however, the bluetooth and the camera do not work, as well as the fingerprint reader. Now what I don't understand is why, in a version prior to 22.04 I can install Ubuntu, but with 22.04 and 24.04 alpha, I can't. If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The bluetooth is not working after intall Ubuntu 22.04. I was searching in the net and it is impossible for me find a solution. Any Idea?

Comment: I have installled ubuntu 24.04 (2024-03-11 07:23), the problems continue. I can not installed,.stop the instalation in: New USB device found

Comment: Apparently you have now managed to install Ubuntu 22.04. Could you please answer your own question here? Admittedly you still have issues with Bluetooth and USB devices, but you have already posted two separate questions about that.

Comment: Jos: With Hp Specter x360 14-eu0174ng inkl. USB-C Hub & Pen 14" 2.8k OLED Touch 120Hz, Intel Ultra 7-155Hx22, 32GB RAM, 1TB SSD. With Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 and 24.04 do not detected bluetooth, wifi, sound card, bright buttoms, touch screen, pen, camera, etc. Please, I need help!

Comment: Jos: I can install ubuntu 22.04 via 20.04. However do not detected bluetooth, wifi, sound card, bright buttoms, touch screen, pen, camera, etc. Please, I need help!